# create page maintenance page in angular js

Tags: angularjs

How to setup maintenance page when my application runing in production and value should be in Boolean so that we switch modes from maintenance to normal and vice versa in angular js

Using route concept

Answer (score 2):

We did it this way:
I created a normal HTML page and changed my gruntfile, that this file will not be minified.
After that, we did the configurations for showing this Error or Maintanance sites via Load Balancer.
A other possible solution for that, is to create a interceptor like shown here 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

At this interceptor you could call the Maintanance Page if a specific statuscode is sent by the server. If you create a http interceptor, each request to the backend will go through it.